# Extract last value of list in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column `location` which contains a lot of text and then an actual location code. I'm trying to extract out the location code, and I figured out if I split the string on spaces then I can just grab the last item in each list. For example, in the df below the column `location` is the original column and after applying my split I now have `location_split`.

```
  | location             | location_split
0 | Town (123)           | ['Town', '(123)']
1 | Town Town (123AB)    | ['Town', 'Town', '(123AB)']
2 | Town (40832) (123BC) | ['Town', '(40832)', '(123BC)']
3 | Town (987)           | ['Town', '(987)']
```

But, how do I make it so that I can pull out the last item in the list and have that be the value for `location_split`? Something like `df['location']=df['location_split'][-1]` and end up with the `location` column below. I did attempt regex, but since some rows have multiple parentheses containing numbers it couldn't differentiate, but splitting them and then grabbing the last item on the list seems the most foolproof.

```
  | location
0 | (123)
1 | (123AB)
2 | (123BC)
3 | (987)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str` accessor

```py
df['location'] = df['location_split'].str[-1]
# or
df['location'] = df['location_split'].str.get(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
df['location'] = df['location'].astype(str).str.extract('(\(.*\))')
```